# JSON Recognized as Invalid Through Stream When Using UTF-8

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to parse a large JSON file using a stream.  If the file is encoded in ANSI I have no trouble, but if the file is UTF-8 formatted it throws an error:

> stream.js:74
>   throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
>         ^
>   Error: Invalid JSON (Unexpected "ï" at position 0 in state STOP)

the portion of my code where it fails looks like this:

```
fileStream = fs.createReadStream(jsonfile, { encoding: 'utf8' });
                        fileStream.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
                            .pipe(es.through(function (data) { .....
```

Any Ideas why it doesn't recognize the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it's heaving trouble with the Byte Order Mark "ï»¿" in the beginning of a UTF-8 File.
( see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark )

you could try the *solution* to set the start pointer position from 0 to 3. I reckon this is quite hacky, but it is one way of doing it.

see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options for how to do it and further info.

Comment: Awesome that works for me for now.  I wasnt aware of the Byte Order Mark.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You're welcome @JustinLevine. If this solved your problem, consider marking the answer as accepted. Thank you.